# Intercepting network errors on apollo-module using Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, apollo, nuxt.js, apollo-client, vue-apollo

I'm using `nuxt` with `apollo-module` and I need to intercept possible network errors (401/403's to be more specific) so I can show some error modal and log out my user. In the documentation I see that inside the `nuxt.config.js` you can do like:

```
  apollo: {
    tokenName: 'Authorization',
    authenticationType: 'Bearer',
    errorHandler(error) { do something }
  }
...
```

But inside that config file, I can't access the app features that I need (like a errors modal or my router, for instance). Is there any way to archive it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use apollo-error-link

```
  apollo: {
    clientConfigs: {
      default: '~/apollox/client-configs/default.js'
    }
  },
```

And here config

```
import { onError } from 'apollo-link-error'

export default function(ctx) {
  const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {

  })
  return {
    link: errorLink,

    // required
    httpEndpoint: ctx.app.$env.GRAPHQL_URL,

    httpLinkOptions: {
      credentials: 'same-origin'
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks so much. Btw I think you meant to write `apollo` instead of `apollox` in `default: '~/apollox/client-configs/default.js'` ?

Comment: you can name the files however you want